# PowerShell: Converting a hex variable into a single (float32) big endian variable

Tags: arrays, powershell, hex, endianness

How can I convert a big-endian hex-variable = `'0x41fe89de'` into a `[single]` (float32) variable?

The result has to be `31,8173179626465`.

I only know the way with `[double] "0x41fe89de"`, getting the result `1107200478`.

Comment: Where is the hex var from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# Input: a string representing a number or big-endian byte sequence
# in hexadecimal form.
$hex = '0x41fe89de'

# Convert the hex input string to a byte array.
$byteArray = [byte[]] ($hex -replace '^0x' -split '(..)' -ne '' -replace '^', '0x')

# Convert from big-endian to little-endian, if necessary, by
# reversing the order of the bytes to match the platform's.
if ([BitConverter]::IsLittleEndian) {
  [Array]::Reverse($byteArray)
}

# Convert to a platform-native [single] instance.
[BitConverter]::ToSingle($byteArray, 0)
```

The above yields `31.81732` (with the default output formatting).

- The technique used to convert the hex string to a byte array is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60065438/45375).
- The conversion of the byte array to a platform-native `[single]` instance ([`System.Single`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Single)) is performed via the [`System.BitConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.BitConverter) class.

  - Note that the number of bytes passed to `::ToSingle()` must be an exact match for the number of bytes that make up the target type; in this case, `4` bytes are required, because `[single]` is a `32`-bit type (`4` bytes times `8` bits); if necessary and appropriate, provide an array that is padded with `0` bytes; use an expression such as `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf([single] 0)` to determine the required byte count.

Comment: The snmp code is here.  I basically turned the endian bytes into an integer by hand.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054622/how-to-read-snmp-oid-output-bits/48934105#48934105